# Qn on jquery plugin (.scrollPagination)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've a piece of code here i got from GitHub. Its a Jquery scroll pagination plugin.

https://github.com/andferminiano/jquery-scroll-pagination/tree/master

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    var count=$('#existing_campaign li').length;
    $('#existing_campaign').scrollPagination({
        'contentPage': '/cs_directory/helpers/campaigns_and_chats.php', // the url you are fetching the results
        'contentData': {"count":count}, // these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
        'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
        'heightOffset': 10, // it gonna request when scroll is 10 pixels before the page ends
        'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load function, you can display a preloader div
            $('#loading').fadeIn();
            alert($('#existing_campaign li').length);
        },
        'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ // after loading content, you can use this function to animate your new elements
             $('#loading').fadeOut();
             var i = 0;
             $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
             if ($('#existing_campaign li').length > 1000){ // if more than 100 results already loaded, then stop pagination (only for testing)
                $('#nomoreresults').fadeIn();
                $('#existing_campaign').stopScrollPagination();
             }
        }
    });

    // code for fade in element by element
    $.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
        var delay = 0;
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
            delay += 100;
        });
    };        
});
```

I'm not sure why but i keep getting the same values for my contentData after sending it over to contentPage for processing, regardless how many times i've activated the function and appended my list from contentPage.

I think its a caching problem but i'm not sure how i can clear the cache. Tried inserting as an option in .scrollPagination but doesn't work as well.

Wonder how i'm going to get through this. I know this can be done else how will i be able to group my `<li>`'s from my content page to display bit by bit?

The documentation is a little scarce on its options so i got to come here looking for answers. Hopefully, someone can provide some answers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I fixed it this changing de content data in the BeforeLoad event and incrementing the page in the afterLoad event like this:

```
function initInfiniteScroll(data){

$('#my-div').scrollPagination({
    'contentPage': url,
    'scrollTarget': $(window),
    'heightOffset': 1,
    'AjaxAsync': true,
    'beforeLoad': function () {
        $(this).attr('contentData', data); // setting the contentData
    }, ...
 'afterLoad': function (loadedData) {
            ...
            data.currentPage++; //Incrementing the page

}
```